# How to send ether to addresses from an array made of a struct?

Tags: solidity

I apologise if this has been asked before. I am new here and new to programming in general.
So i am trying to send ether to multiple addresses in one transaction (like a multisend).
I have a struct stored in an array :

```
struct Employee {
    address payable to;
    string name;
    uint256 startTime;
}


Employee[] public employee;

function addEmployee(address payable _to, string memory _name) public {
    require(_to != address(0), "Address can't be 0x0");
    employee.push(Employee(_to, _name, block.timestamp));
    totalEmployee++;
}

function sendPayment() public payable {}
```

Is there any way to send ether to all the addresses stored in that array in a single transaction considering the amount sent is the same.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What did you try? Solidity has a couple of ways to send ether `.transfer`, `.send`, `.{value: }call`.

Comment: Hey, i am trying using call. but my issue here is getting the addresses from the struct that is inside that array. 
I don't have logic to grab that value

Comment: It should be quite obvious `employee[index].to`, where `index` is the position of in the array you want to access.